# Equivalent of $requireAuth in Firebase 3.0

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

What is the equivalent way of doing `$requireAuth` in Firebase 3.0. I searched it everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$requireAuth` is an AngularFire function. Which version of AngularFire are you using? And which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular-1.5.6, AngularFire-2.0.2, Firebase-3.3.0 @cartant

Answer (score 0):

There is a migration guide for moving from **AngularFire** 1.x.x to 2.x.x [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md#firebaseauth-method-renames--signature-changes).

Note that there have been a considerable number of [method renames](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md#firebaseauth-method-renames--signature-changes).

`$requireAuth` is now named `$requireSignIn()` and the documentation for that function is [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#requiresignin)

> `$requireSignIn()`
>
> Helper method which returns a promise fulfilled with the current authentication state if the user is authenticated but otherwise rejects the promise. This is intended to be used in the `resolve()` method of Angular routers to prevented unauthenticated users from seeing authenticated pages momentarily during page load. See the "[Using Authentication with Routers](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers)" section of our AngularFire guide for more information and a full example.

Comment: Its showing an error that $requireSignIn() is not a function.   @cartant

Comment: With the absence of any code, it's difficult to offer advice or explanation. The migration documents say that `$requireSignIn` is now the function name. I can only suggest that you verify that the correct version of AngularFire is being used, that the correct service is being injected and that the function is being called on said service.